# customize selected text of android autocompletetextview

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm using AutoCompleteTextView in android with my custom entities like `CountryEntity`

this class is used in two places, one for selecting country in profile form and one for choosing phone number prefixes in contact form

when I use AutoCompleteTextView, view displays `CountryEntity.toString()` when an item will be selected, but I need to display Name of country in one place and code prefix in another place.

Is there any way to customize how selected item displayed?

Answer (score 0):

finally reached to method `convertSelectionToString` in `AutoCompeleteTextView`
so creating a subclass of `AutoCompeleteTextView` and override `convertSelectionToString` solved my problem